# "Quit following" vs "stopped following" tv shows

Tags: word-choice, american-english

Which one's correct?

> I have quitted following tv shows
>   I have stopped following tv shows.

Answer (score 1):

[To quit something means to leave it or stop doing it](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quit), so

> I quit following them

means the same as

> I stopped following them

When it means "to stop doing something", *quit* is a little less formal than *stop*, but the meaning is the same.

*Quit* is usually the first-person present and past tense and the participle of *to quit*, though, and *quitted* is the older way of conjugating it.  So it would normally be used today like

> I **get** tired, **have** a drink, and **quit** working.

or

> Yesterday I **got** tired, **had** a drink, and **quit** working.  Now I **have quit** working entirely.

"Have quitted" will sound very old-fashioned and a little strange to American English speakers - [you can see how the usage has changed in the last two hundred years](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20quit%2Chave%20quitted&year_start=1800&year_end=2000).  I would recommend just using "quit".